# Get merge WHEN NOT MATCHED output into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to insert the not matched output to two tables. When I try to insert the output of the stored procedure it takes all the updated values as well to the new table not only the not matched values to the 'table'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[identify]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO [test].[dbo].[warehouse] AS dim
    USING [test].[dbo].[staging] AS stg
        ON dim.[first_name] = stg.first_name
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            dim.[first_name] = stg.first_name,
            dim.last_name = stg.last_name,
            dim.created_date = stg.created_date,
            dim.modified_date = stg.modified_date,
            dim.gender = stg.gender
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(first_name, last_name, created_date, modified_date, gender)
        VALUES(first_name, last_name,created_date, modified_date,gender)
    OUTPUT Inserted.first_name, Inserted.last_name INTO test (first_name,last_name);

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[identify]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @UpdatedRows TABLE
    (
        action NVARCHAR(10),
        first_name NVARCHAR(50),
        old_last_name NVARCHAR(50),
        new_last_name NVARCHAR(50)
    );

    MERGE INTO [dbo].[warehouse] AS dim
    USING [dbo].[staging] AS stg
        ON dim.[first_name] = stg.first_name
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            [first_name] = stg.first_name,
            last_name = stg.last_name,
            created_date = stg.created_date,
            modified_date = stg.modified_date,
            gender = stg.gender
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(first_name, last_name, created_date, modified_date, gender)
        VALUES(stg.first_name, stg.last_name, stg.created_date, stg.modified_date, stg.gender)
    OUTPUT $action AS action, Inserted.first_name AS first_name, Deleted.last_name AS old_last_name, Inserted.last_name AS new_last_name
    INTO @UpdatedRows;

    INSERT INTO test (action, first_name, last_name)
    SELECT action, first_name, old_last_name
    FROM @UpdatedRows
    WHERE action = 'UPDATE';

    INSERT INTO test (action, first_name, last_name)
    SELECT action, first_name, new_last_name
    FROM @UpdatedRows
    WHERE action = 'INSERT';
END;
```

Here a table variable `@UpdatedRows` is declared which records the action performed and can then be used to insert into multiple tables as required.

Comment: Your handling of old and new last_names is a bit weird... why not do the same for first_name?

Comment: Merge is performed on the basis of first_name so i guess it's not necessary. What do you think ?

Comment: UPDATE SET
dim.[first_name] = stg.first_name

i guess this is unnecessary as well

Comment: Hi Thank you so much,  I added this code to the stored procedure
INSERT INTO test(first_name,last_name) SELECT first_name,last_name FROM warehouse
WHERE 1=1
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test AS Dim
WHERE Dim.first_name = warehouse.first_name)


Don't know whether this is efficient or not. Is there any way we can get the only inserted values without creating a temp table

Comment: @SanjulaDissanayake no - if you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you'll see that the `output` clause always applies to all the actions carried out by the merge, there is no way to filter it at that point.

Comment: @SanjulaDissanayake i have posted  the answer without the temp table.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[identify]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO [dbo].[warehouse] AS dim
    USING [dbo].[staging] AS stg
        ON dim.[first_name] = stg.first_name
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            [first_name] = stg.first_name,
            last_name = stg.last_name,
            created_date = stg.created_date,
            modified_date = stg.modified_date,
            gender = stg.gender
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(first_name, last_name, created_date, modified_date, gender)
        VALUES(stg.first_name, stg.last_name, stg.created_date, stg.modified_date, stg.gender)
    OUTPUT Inserted.first_name AS first_name, IsNull(Deleted.last_name,Inserted.last_name) AS old_last_name
    INTO test;
END;
```

Comment: That doesn't sound work... OP had already tried that. And why did you declare the variables? OP doesn't want the matched updates into the test table.

Comment: IsNull(Deleted.last_name,Inserted.last_name) AS old_last_name. This part was added and it works .

Comment: @SanjulaDissanayake  does this approach works as per you need?

Comment: OP specifically said only log entries when not matched, this solution also logs entities that do match

Comment: @AtnapRK Here i want to insert only the no matched entries to the test table

Comment: Directly inserting or not inserting based on a condition in the OUTPUT clause is not supported in SQL Server.  One workaround is to insert null value if extra table is not intended to be created.


OUTPUT        
       CASE 
            WHEN stg.$action = 'INSERT' THEN Inserted.first_name
            ELSE NULL
       END AS first_name,
       CASE 
            WHEN stg.$action = 'INSERT' THEN Inserted.last_name
            ELSE NULL
       END AS last_name
 INTO test;

Comment: @AtnapRK your other solution is perfect... much better than writing null or anything. I can't work out why you've left this one here when it clearly doesn't address the question.